# LINQ over local variables

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This might seems trivial for some of you but I'm confused about these two examples below.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
int i = 0;

var simpleQuery =
    from num in numbers
    select ++i;

foreach (var item in simpleQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine("v = {0}, i = {1}", item, i); // now i is incremented          
}
```

Outputs:

```
v = 1, i = 1
v = 2, i = 2
v = 3, i = 3
v = 4, i = 4
v = 5, i = 5
v = 6, i = 6
v = 7, i = 7
v = 8, i = 8
v = 9, i = 9
v = 10, i = 10
```

It updates the value of i and everything is fine up to this point. But when I tried to update the elements of array, it just doesn't work.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
var simpleQuery =
    from num in numbers
    select ++num;

int i = 0;
foreach (var item in simpleQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine("v = {0}, num = {1}", item, numbers[i++]); // now num is NOT incremented???
}
```

Outputs:

```
v = 6, num = 5
v = 5, num = 4
v = 2, num = 1
v = 4, num = 3
v = 10, num = 9
v = 9, num = 8
v = 7, num = 6
v = 8, num = 7
v = 3, num = 2
v = 1, num = 0
```

What might be the reason behind this?

**Edit:**
I thought the second example will output:

```
v = 6, num = 6
v = 5, num = 5
v = 2, num = 2
v = 4, num = 4
v = 10, num = 10
v = 9, num = 9
v = 7, num = 7
v = 8, num = 8
v = 3, num = 3
v = 1, num = 1
```

Comment: Your code works fine. What do you want to do? `select ++i;` dont related your array. You just increment i for each numbers array item

Comment: The confusing part is that the value of i changes because of "select ++i" but the value of num is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query actually looks like

```
numbers.Select(num => ++num)
```

Which is actually call to extension method

```
Enumerable.Select(numbers, new Func<int, int>(num => ++num))
```

This method executes selector on each item of array. Selector is an anonymous function (i.e. name for this function will be generated by compiler). And each item is passed to that function. And here is reason why items in array stay unchanged - integer is a value type. Value types are passed by value (i.e. copy of item is created, instead of passing reference to item). So, inside selector copy is modified and returned. This does not affect original item in array.

In first case you have captured reference to `i` variable in delegate, thats why `i` is changed:

```
Enumerable.Select(numbers, new Func<int, int>(num => ++i))
```

Array items are still passed here as method argument, but `i` is captured in method body. Actually such variables (which are part of method body) are replaced by compiler - in your first case variable `i` is moved to fields of class, and all calls to that variable are replaced with calls to class field. I.e. in first case compiled code will look like:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foreach(int num in numbers)
   Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar(num));
```

Where `Foo` is a generated nested class, and `Bar` is a selector delegate, which is a method, generated in that class.

```
private class Foo
{
   private int _i; // variable is captured by delegate

   public int Bar(int x)
   {
       _i = _i + 1; // thats why it has new value on next call
       return _i;
   }
}
```

Comment: @BerkArslan I added sample, which explains in more detail why you first code works. I think it will be useful to investigate :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is operating on a reference to `i` (captured as part of a closure), while your second query is operating on copies of each array element, not references. The expressions passed to LINQ queries map to lambda expressions, and the variables inputted to a lambda expression (such as `num` in your example) are copies for values types, not references.

Answer (score 0):

```
var simpleQuery =
from num in numbers
select ++i;
```

means:

```
for(int i=0; i<numbers.Length; i++)
{
    simpleQuery.Add(++i);
}
```

And

```
var simpleQuery =
from num in numbers
select ++num;
```

means:

```
for(int i=0; i<numbers.Length; i++)
{
    simpleQuery.Add(numbers[i] + 1);
}
```

Comment: So you think that ++i will change the value of i whereas ++num will not change the value of the corresponding array item

Comment: What do you want to do? Or you just try to understand your code working

Comment: In your second example, you fetch +1 of each item.

Comment: I just want to understand the reason. Why the value of i changes but the value of the items in array does not. In the first example, i's value changes because when I iterate over the list in foreach, it will increment i(by using i's reference) and then puts it into the result list. And in the second example I again thought, while I iterate over the list, it will firstly increment num(which references an array element by num's reference) and then puts it into the result. But it seems when I use ++num it doesn't increment the value by using num's reference